# Why do Zend Server CE error pages show up in plain text? Is there a fix?

Tags: apache, apache2, zend-server-ce, php

In MAMP error pages show up like this [image]

In Zend Server CE my error pages show up like this making it difficult to read:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I copied the MAMP xdebug.so file over to zend server ce directory and edited the php.ini file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add / modify this setting in your php.ini:

```
html_errors = On
```

Comment: Xdebug is installed and enabled